# I/O error and Bad request exception on POST request for apis on IIS server

Tags: rest, iis

I have service running on IIS server written in .net compiled on 32 bit.

After processing few apis I start getting below log on my java application

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://* Connection reset; nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

and IIS server throws exception as below image

[image]

Apart from this I am also getting at some other point of time

> 400 Bad Request

without any exception on IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have Visual Studio installed on a production WebServer.  I would first uninstall Visual Studio and if that popup remains, remove Just-In-Time debugging.  This will allow the exceptions in your application to flow as they should.   Once that happens, verify you are still getting the same error messages and check the Windows Application Event Log for additional information.